# Does a complex function is 1-1 and continuous on a open and connected set imply its inverse function is continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

It is well known that if a real-valued function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and 1-1, then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous where $I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}.$ I wonder if it is also true for complex function, i.e., if $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and 1-1, then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. Here $D$ is open and connected in $\mathbb{C}.$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This is true more generally for $\mathbb{R}^n$: if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is injective and continuous, then the image $V$ of $f$ is open and the inverse map $f^{-1}:V\to U$ is continuous.  This is known as ["invariance of domain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). The proof for $n>1$ is considerably more difficult than the proof for $n=1$, though, and requires tools from algebraic topology.